# Транскрипция слова "фортепиано"

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия, транскрипция

Какая транскрипция у слова "фортепиано"? [ф ъ р т ъ пʼ и а́ н ъ] — вот так или по-другому?

Answer (score 1):

Какая транскрипция у слова "фортепиано"? фъртъпʼиа́нъ вот так? или по-другому? например, фърты(э)пʼа́нъ , где (э) маленькая над ы ,как бы со звучанием э.
        Слово фортепиано заимствовано из итальянского, образовано из двух "форте" и "пиано" (громко и тихо). Вариант фортепьяно считается разговорным, стилистически сниженным. Я думаю, первая транскрипция верна. Чтобы вторая транскрипция соответствовала произношению слова "фортепьяно", туда надо добавить звук "йот". Это будет выглядеть так: фърты(э)пʼЙа́нъ, тогда в первом предударном слоге Е будет обозначать ы(э) (Ы с призвуком Э).